# 'RawTurtle' object has no attribute 'Turtle'

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I saw the sorting example in turtle demo which python includes and I would like to add similar animations in my program. My program is based in tkinter and I would like to insert turtle animations in a tkinter canvas (with `RawTurtle`) so first I tried to create a black box in the canvas and I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'RawTurtle' object has no attribute 'Turtle'
```

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter
from turtle import *

class MyApp():

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.p = parent
        self.f = tkinter.Frame(self.p).pack()
        self.c = tkinter.Canvas(self.f, height = '640', width = '1000')
        self.c.pack()
        self.t = RawTurtle(self.c)
        self.main(5)

    def main(self, size):
        self.t.size = size
        self.t.Turtle.__init__(self, shape="square", visible=False)
        self.t.pu()
        self.t.shapesize(5, 1.5, 2)
        self.t.fillcolor('black')
        self.t.st()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root= tkinter.Tk()
    frame = MyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you could create own animation without Turtle - it can be easier to control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much have it -- those two settings you were trying to change via the non-existent `Turtle()` instance method can be handled when creating the `RawTurtle`:

```
import tkinter
from turtle import RawTurtle

class MyApp():

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.p = parent
        self.f = tkinter.Frame(self.p).pack()
        self.c = tkinter.Canvas(self.f, height=640, width=1000)
        self.c.pack()
        self.t = RawTurtle(self.c, shape='square', visible=False)
        self.main(5)

    def main(self, size):
        self.t.size = size  # does nothing if stamping with pen up
        self.t.penup()
        self.t.shapesize(5, 1.5, 2)
        self.t.fillcolor('black')  # the default
        self.t.stamp()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    frame = MyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```